# How can I set values to Firestore from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a grading app and I wanted to list students from Firestore and fill their grades and I have got the list for the students list but I cant get the number to work I have a working attendance code that only uses boolean values
here is the working code for booleans

```
Switch(
                                  value: switchStates[
                                      students[index].data()["id"]],
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      stateofvalue = value;
                                    });
                                    onSwitchChanged(
                                        students[index].data()["id"], value);
                                  },
                                  activeColor: Color(0xff2fbd9f),
                                ),
```

this is how I call the values

```
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
Future<void> markAttendance() {
    Map<String, dynamic> resultMap = {};
    var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    String todaysDate = formatter.format(now);

    switchStates.forEach((key, value) {
      keys.add(key);
      values.add(value);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      resultMap["${keys[i]}"] = values[i];
    }
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("data")
        .doc("attendance")
        .collection("school")
        .doc(todaysDate)
        .set(resultMap);
  }
```

and this is how I set th value but now I want to set grades in the same manner how can I manage to do that by replacing `Switch()` with `TextFeild()`

Comment: how many grades per student? is it just one overall grade per student? or is it multiple grades for different courses per student?

Comment: what type of grade do you wish to enter ? You can have a dropdown for simplicity!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TextField` with `onSubmitted` or `onChanged` callbacks.

```
TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  onSubmitted: (text) {
    sendMessage(text);
    _controller.clear();
  },
  onChanged: () {},
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the user ID, you could try something like this

```
Firestore.instance
                .collection("users")
                .document(userId)
                .get().then((value) => value.update({
        field: value
    })
```

I mean, get the collection and then update it individually